# How to create datatable dataframe from a matrix of values (list of lists) and a list of features, using python datatable lib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a list of ***n*** features :

```
lf = ['f1','f2',...,'fn']
```

Given a list of ***m*** lists, each nested list contain ***n*** value (a matrix of ***m*** rows and ***n*** columns):

```
matrix =  
[
[r0_v1, r0_v2, ..., r0_vn]  
[r1_v1, r1_v2, ..., r1_vn]  
.
.
.
[rm_v1, rm_v2, ..., rm_vn]  
]
```

What is the correct way to create a datatable datafarme using [python datatable library](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/v0.10.1/) ?

I tried something similar to pandas dataframe in the following source code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datatable as dt

# pandas create dataframe
pd_df = pd.DataFrame(matrix,columns=lf) # work fine

# datatable create dataframe
dt_df = dt.Frame(matrix,names=lf) # get error, the rows are considered as columns
```

But i get an error ValueError: The names argument contains n elements, which is more than the number of columns being created (m)
Which means that the rows are considered as columns.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To create datatable datafarme from matrix and list of features use `dt.Frame(matrix_values, names=list_features)`
Use `np.array` to convert from list of lists to 2d array: `matrix = np.array(matrix)`

```
import datatable as dt
import numpy as np

lf = ['f1','f2','f3','f4','f5']

matrix = [
    [0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1],
    [2,2,2,2,2],
]

matrix = np.array(matrix)

dt_df = dt.Frame(matrix,names=lf)

print(dt_df)
```